# Pandas dataframe Date time conversion Error:-TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I have data as below dataframe:-

```
    trending_date   publish_date
5407    17.12.12    2017-12-06
5118    17.11.12    2017-12-06
4935    17.10.12    2017-12-06
4476    17.07.12    2017-11-29
4235    17.06.12    2017-11-29
```

I want to convert the data type of above date columns from object to date type.
When I am using below code:-

```
df['trending_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trending_date'], format = '%y.%d.%m')
```

But getting error-"TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable"

Same is case for other column as well.
Can you pleasehelp me.

Comment: Irreproducible for me.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using an older version of pandas. It will be solved by upgrading your pandas hopfully.